# What is the recommended replacement for pip in Debian/Ubuntu where there is no deb package available?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, debian, linux-mint

`sudo apt-get install trac` no longer finds trac.

`sudo apt-git install pip` no longer finds pip, but python has the command:

`python -m ensurepip` that is supposed to do the same thing but instead advises you to try something like:

`sudo apt-git install python-trac` which fails because there is no such package.

`sudo apt-get install python-pip` doesn not find pip (again, they disabled it, so what is the ALTERNATIVE to pip that they want us to use)

`sudo apt-get install python-pip3` does get pip3 which fails when used to find trac, a python2 package, so I'm not looking for pip3, just pip for python2.

So it seems the "super-cow" powers of apt are backfiring here making it more difficult rather than easier to install packages. Do we need to be resort to manual installation from source now? Or is there a Debian-style way of installing pip packages on Debian that don't have corresponding Debian packages?

(The output of `python -m ensurepip` is below:)

```lisp
$ python -m ensurepip
ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python.

Python modules For the system python are usually handled by dpkg and apt-get.

    apt-get install python-<module name>

Install the python-pip package to use pip itself.  Using pip together
with the system python might have unexpected results for any system installed
module, so use it on your own risk, or make sure to only use it in virtual
environments.
```

`E: Unable to locate package python-pip` results from `sudo apt-get install python-pip` as directed by the error message

I don't see why they disable pip rather than modifying pip to check the debian repos first and then falling back on actual pip when the package is not found in debian. Any idea on that?

This is for Mint 20 (Ulyana)

```lisp
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyana main upstream import backport

deb http://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
```

(Maybe this is why people are moving from Ubuntu & Mint to MX & Manjaro)

Comment: Which version of Debian? Debian may have removed Python2, but I doubt they have removed pip from a Python2 install. pip is included in Python 2.7 since version 2.7.9.

Comment: They had removed it. I ended up using a different distro, which made the problem go away. It may be fixed by now.  It was for  Mint 20 (Ulyana) as the original post stated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mint is broken. It works properly in some other Debian based distros like MX.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. Problem exists on Ubuntu 20.04 as well (unsurprisingly, per the error message)

Comment: The simple fix was to use a different distro. That worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you can use

> sudo apt-cache search pip

to find renamed packages easily. Looks like its called python-pip or python3-pip depending on the version you're looking for.

I'll let you find the others :)

Comment: Tried those.
$ sudo apt-get install pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip

Comment: Sounds like you need to double check your sources list for apt. It's located at /etc/apt/sources.list

I am by no means an expert on what "should" be there though. Believe the default is http://deb.debian.org/debian/

I have no issues installed the python-pip package on my system.

Comment: Official debian documentation for context https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Answer (score 1):

Install `python2` from `universe` repository (it is not available in the `main` repository, it is deprecated on favor of `python3`) then install `pip2`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install python2
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

for the perfect installation of pip you must type its in your command line
apt-cache search python3-pip

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for your effort. However, I think your answer doesn't add anything to the problem which hasn't been said by Mathew Hallett already. Please make it clearer what your solution offers, additionally.